# default electron drag project not working as intended

Tags: javascript, file, electron, project, drag

the default electron file drag project (https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/v15.3.0/docs/fiddles/features/drag-and-drop) should from my understanding have a drag icon when the user is dragging a file, however after copying the project per vadum the drag icon does not show up, has there been a change, does it just not work or am I missing something?

I'm using the latest build of windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question first: It was not changed (no change for this Fiddle since May 19, 2021) and is still working.

For me it looks like this when opening the project with Electron Fiddle (Windows 10 21H1 x64, build 19043.1288) and Electron v13.1.7:
[image: Drag and Drop Example]

According to the [source code](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/b6c9110923ac9c2a51d8a1f1dac61a5e5bef27a1/docs/fiddles/features/drag-and-drop/main.js#L25-L27), this is the icon that should be visible: https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/drag-and-drop.png

Which version of Electron are you using? And, just to be sure, you have opened the project with Electron (Fiddle) and not in your browser by clicking on the `index.html` file, correct?